# Turning a cascading one to one relationship into a one to many

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a table that contains Items and their details.
The table contains the ItemID and also "Alt_ItemID" which stores another ItemID that can be used in place of the original Item. eg.

ItemID, Item_Description, Alt_ItemID

ABC123, Square Brick, ABC456

ABC456, Almost Square Brick, null

so Item ABC123 can have item ABC456 used in it's place if we run out of stock.

These relationships can continue so ABC456 could have an alternate of DEF123 which could be used in place of either ABC123 or ABC456. The 'cascade' can go on indefinitely (some items have 20-30 alternatives listed in their usage priority order this way)

I'm using a cursor (slow i know) to loop through the table as below and compile a one to many (global so i can see how far it's got) temp table showing the "original" item and all the possible cascaded items. The problem is, at its current rate it will take ~10 hours to complete so it's not something we could use in live reporting (and due to the fluid nature of the Items table would not suit being stored periodically).

Any ideas on if this could be done a bit quicker using an arrangement of joins/CTEs?

NB. the "@AltItem <> @Part_num" and "@AltItem <> ''" are unfortunately necessary because of bad data with self referencing 'cascades' and annoying blanks.

```
 create table ##Alternatives (ItemID varchar(50), Alt_ItemID varchar(50))


 Declare @ItemID AS Nvarchar(MAX) 
 DEclare @AltItem as nvarchar(max)



 DECLARE Alternatives CURSOR FOR                
    SELECT ItemID                           
    FROM DatabaseName.dbo.ItemTable             


 OPEN Alternatives                      

 FETCH NEXT FROM Alternatives   
 INTO @ItemID       

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
 BEGIN  

 select @AltItem = Alt_ItemID from DatabaseName.dbo.ItemTable where ItemID = @ItemID and Alt_ItemID <> @ItemID

                while  @AltItem is not null and @AltItem <> '' and @AltItem <> @ItemID
                 begin
                 insert into ##Alternatives values (@ItemID, Alt_ItemID)
                 select @AltItem = Alt_ItemID from DatabaseName.dbo.ItemTable
                  where ItemID = @AltItem and Alt_ItemID <> @AltItem and Alt_ItemID <> @ItemID

                end  
 FETCH NEXT FROM Alternatives   
 INTO @ItemID  
 END   
 CLOSE Alternatives;  
 DEALLOCATE Alternatives;  


 select * from ##Alternatives
 --drop table ##Alternatives
```

Comment: I just did a super quick glance but perhaps a self join here?  OR  perhaps use a recursive cte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer using a recursive CTE:

**SetUp**

```
CREATE TABLE #ItemTable
(
ItemID varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY, 
Item_Description varchar(50), 
Alt_ItemID varchar(10) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #ItemTable
VALUES ('ABC123', 'Square Brick', 'ABC456'),
        ('ABC456', 'Almost Square Brick', null),
        ('DEF123', 'Sphere', 'GHI789'),
        ('GHI789', 'Oval', 'XYZ123'),
        ('XYZ123', 'Circle', NULL)
```

**Common Table Expression Query**

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    -- Find the top level item
    SELECT ItemId As ParentItemId, ItemId, Item_Description, Alt_ItemId, 0 As Level
    FROM #ItemTable IT1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #ItemTable IT2 WHERE IT1.ItemID = IT2.Alt_ItemId)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CTE.ParentItemId As ParentItemId, IT1.ItemId, IT1.Item_Description, IT1.Alt_ItemId, CTE.Level + 1 As Level
    FROM #ItemTable IT1
    INNER JOIN CTE
        ON CTE.Alt_ItemId = IT1.ItemId
)
SELECT ParentItemId, ItemId, Item_Description
FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.LEvel > 0
ORDER By ParentItemId
```

**Results:**

```
ParentItemId    ItemId  Item_Description
------------    ------  -------------------
ABC123          ABC456  Almost Square Brick
DEF123          GHI789  Oval
DEF123          XYZ123  Circle
```

Comment: Thanks, this works very nicely. I created a similar one on the back of Mark Schultheiss' comment above, very similar structure but with I'll study yours and compare the differences. My first time dabbling in recursive CTEs so this will help A LOT.